# How to calculate difference in dates for column with smallest value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that contains 3 column dates: CREATED, CLOSED and EXPIRED.
I need to calculate the difference in date between either CLOSED or EXPIRED and CREATED.
I need to select the SMALLER value between CLOSED and EXPIRED and then calculate the difference to CREATED.
If they have the same date, I need to select EXPIRED.

[image]

In the example above:

```
For account_id =1, the difference in date should be: EXPIRED - CREATED. 
For account_id = 2, the difference in date should be EXPIRED - CREATED.
For account_id = 3, the difference in date should be CLOSED - EXPIRED.
```

Is there a way to do this, to select the smaller value between CLOSED and EXPIRED, and based on this calculate the difference in date with CREATED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LEAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html) or GREATEST is how you pick the min/max between values.

```
SELECT 
   created, expired, closed,
   LEAST(expired, closed) as min_exp_clo,
   DATEDIFF('days', created, min_exp_clo) as date_diff_days
FROM table
```

and have a extra column free version, just mash together:

```
SELECT 
   created, expired, closed,
   DATEDIFF('days', created, LEAST(expired, closed)) as date_diff_days
FROM table
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! Do you know how to do this without creating another column (min_exp_clo)? Can I do this within the DATEDIFF function?

Comment: @lalaland just updated showing how to mash them together. Apart allows for easer seeing how the parts/steps can be done, but you can compose most things together.

Comment: Thank you so much!